# Facebook: Friends' likes to posts on pages which were done via api are not visible in friends' feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

When posting manually to a page as admin, all friends' likes to these posts appear in their feed.

**But when posting via graph api to the same page, friends' likes to these posts do not appear in their feed**.

While using the following scope ...

```
'scope' => 'read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages'
```

... and retrieving the access_token via me/accounts, my post contains this information ...

```
'name',
'message',
'link',
'caption',
'description',
'picture',
'access_token'
```

Additionally I tried adding a targeting value to the post ...

```
'targeting' => array('value' => 'EVERYONE'),
```

... or

```
'privacy' => array('value' => 'EVERYONE'),
```

... although the latter is not accepted anyways, both have no influence on this issue.

**I have noticed that manual posts to a page have a small globe icon beside the '1 minute ago' ... while api posts to a page have not.**

Is this a restriction set by Facebook, may this be a privacy setting, or am I doing anything wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the on-facebook notifications that page admins see when people interact with their posts? These aren't available for posts made via the API

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a Facebook bug:

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/154484061346461